# YouTube Data API (search for a channel)

Tags: youtube-data-api

Using the YouTube Data API, I can find a channel with the "search" API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Alexander+condrashov&type=channel&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

This gives me one object in my items array.

But this is a "search" API, not a "channel" API.

I think that the correct way to find a channel is to use "Channels: list" API.

Trying to find channel by username gives me zero objects in my items array:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&forUsername=Alexander+kondrashov&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Has anyone succeeded in using "Channels: list" with "forUsername" to find a channel?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and you may have already figured something out, but unfortunately YouTube's Channels API isn't great for finding channels reliably for anything other than the channel's ID. As a workaround, I combine the two approaches to get a realiable result (though it takes two queries and costs more quota which is lame sauce).

For example (in C# using the Google SDKs):

```
public async Task<Channel> GetChannelByUsername(string username)
{
    try
    {
        var channel = default(Channel);
        var searchRequest = this.youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchRequest.Q = username;
        searchRequest.Type = "channel";

        var searchResults = await searchRequest.ExecuteAsync();
        if (searchResults != null && searchResults.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var searchResult = searchResults.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Snippet.ChannelTitle.ToLower() == username);
            if (searchResult != null && searchResult.Snippet != null)
            {
                var channelSearchResult = searchResult.Snippet;
                var channelListRequest = this.youtubeService.Channels.List("snippet");
                channelListRequest.Id = channelSearchResult.ChannelId;

                var channelListResult = await channelListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
                if(channelListResult != null)
                {
                    channel = channelListResult.Items.FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
        }

        return channel;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle Exception
    }
}
```